# Object affect volume shadow only

Tags: shadows, volumetrics

I'm trying to have an object cast volume shadow only, but it should NOT cast shadow nor be visible to the camera. Is this even possible?

[image: Reference image]

Here's my test file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, it worked after I remade the test scene

[image: it worked]

here's the updated blend file‍♀️

[image]